# Understanding tomcat docker files

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat, docker

I am looking at the below tomcat docker file:

https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/blob/5c8b74e495a1b63116b524407941b15eef58a7fe/8.0/jre8/Dockerfile

But should it not specify an OS as base image  (e.g. Ubuntu, debian, etc.)?

I basically just need a docker file that contains ubuntu 16.x, java 8 and tomcat 8. But not really sure why I need that many lines in the above dockerfile to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

Docker uses the FROM directive to indicate base images. If you traverse it along you get to see

```
FROM debian:stretch
```

on https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/master/stretch/curl/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Image contains tomcat APR library which needs to be compiled on the docker image. Library is not required for tomcat to run but it's recommended to have it in production as it's fast and scalable connector.

Answer (score 0):

A `Dockerfile` can specify `FROM` using any valid Docker image. You often get a hierarchy of images, one that has the base OS installed and then children that customise the OS for running certain application types e.g. Java apps, Node apps and so on.

To work out what is in your image, you need to follow up from the hierarchy of `FROM` statements to get a complete picture.

From the `Dockerfile` you link, you can see the `FROM openjdk:8-jre`. This tells us that this `Dockerfile` builds an image based upon the `:latest` tag of the `openjdk:8-jre` image. So that means we can find the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/80490366d49e6781e9dcb5dad8ebf0fb6ec04000/8-jre/Dockerfile) for that image and see that the `openjdk:8-jre` actually builds on the [buildpack-deps:stretch-curl](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/9f60e19008458220114f1a0b6cd3710f1015d402/stretch/curl/Dockerfile) image, which in turn builds on the [debian:stretch](https://github.com/debuerreotype/docker-debian-artifacts/blob/97dc072ae1e6c66c1ccc71ead334ce5d5fc201f0/stretch/Dockerfile) image.

Alternatively you can use `docker history` against the image e.g. `docker history openjdk:8-jre` to see the list of layers that the image consists of.

Comment: ok so when I look at debian:stretch it in turn says FROM scratch which looks like this one: https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch/ so is "scratch" just another term for debian dist? And are those dockerfile names globally unique?

Comment: `scratch` is a special, reserved image that provides a starting point for the creation of base images. Typically you'll see that the basic OS images that just give you an OS e.g. `debian:stretch` will include the `FROM scratch` as they are just giving you an installed OS and nothing else. Docker image names are unique to the repository in which they live. Dockerhub is the main default repo which enforces some level of uniqueness, but there is nothing to stop you build an image of your own called `debian:stretch` in your local repository (other than it becomes confusing!)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see so many lines in some Dockerfiles is that the image builds on a minimal base image. This is considered a very good practice in docker to keep the image small.

Ubuntu image and such are somehow large and are usually not required to achieve the end result of packaging an application.

In the tomcat image, the Dockerfile is buidling on top of the `openjdk:8-jre` image, which itself is built on top of a basic `debian:stretch`. Thus it might not be direct to install tomcat directly in the Dockerfile like you do with Ubuntu.